# Passing dictionary as an argument to another python script

Tags: python, dictionary, arguments

I want to pass a dictionary as an argument to a separate python script as shown below:

```
dict1= {'appid':'facebook'}
subprocess.call('python mypython.py -o' + dict1, shell=True) (Also tried with os.system)
```

Contents of mypython.py:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
parser.add_argument("-o", dest="dict1")
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.dict1:
    op1 = args.dict1
    print op1
```

Traceback details:

```
python parent.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parent.py", line 52, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "mypython.py", line 30, in main
    subprocess.call('python mypython.py -o' + dict1, shell=True)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'dict' objects
```

Now when I convert the dict object to string using str, I hit another issue:

```
dict1={2:11}
tostr=str(dict1)
print (tostr)
os.system('python mypython.py -o '+tostr)

python parent.py
{2: 11}
usage: mypython.py [-h] [-o DICT1]
mypython.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 11}
```

It adds an extra space after : (before 11) and hence it fails. Only workaround is my input is a string:

```
dict1="{2:11}"
os.system('python mypython.py -o '+dict1)
```

It works as expected in the above case.

Can someone suggest me how to pass a dictionary as an argument to another script?

Comment: Why are you doing this via `subprocess`?

Comment: It looks like that you're trying to find a workaround on how to call a function which lies inside file A from file B. Please [read up on the Python tutorial section on modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html). That's the far better solution to your (presumed) problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could cast the dict to a string (`str(dict1)`) and then parse it in the other class with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/converting-a-string-to-dictionary).